# Can I exchange iCloud data between different iCloud accounts

Tags: ios

I have created a collection of notes with the Notes app on my iPad.
How can I transfer these notes in a simple way to the Notes app on my wife's iPad?

More general: How can I exchange notes between different iCloud accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if they are just a few, i would manually send each one by email to your wife's icloud account. then it would be email and have to be manually copied into the notes app, if this is needed.

Comment: Thank you frisbee23. That is the only way I can think of. But… this is a time intensive workflow when the collection is large. I can't imagine Apple has thought of a more user friendly workflow :)

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on the Apple Community forum. And [there](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6060806) was the answer I was waiting for :-)

> You can have multiple iCloud accounts on the same device, but one has to be the "primary".  Any secondary account(s) you add will support things like Mail, Contacts, Calendar, and Notes (but not things like Safari syncing nor Find My iPhone for that account).
>
> So if your wife does not mind you having her iCloud account set up as a secondary account on your iPad, you could then copy a note from your account and paste it into a new note in her account.

Comment: I know this is a very old answer, but could somebody post a link to the documentation to do this?